# Windows 10 boot and reboot hangs

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-10-upgrade

I am running windows 10 on a SSD drive.  I was having freezing issues for a while but when i bought my 1080gtx I had to get the anniversary update.  After this update my PC hangs on the please wait or restarting windows until i hit that power btn. I have timed it for 20 minutes at one point.

Other times I get past this it will become unresponsive at the windows login window. And finally some times works great! then the start bar or other windows features being to freeze and eventually the whole PC freezes.

Is there a good fix for this? Do i have to wipe it and start clean? How do I do that on a windows update to 10 from 8?

Answer (score 0):

Was one of my drives went bad that the OS was not on.